# Check all values in array using a loop

Tags: verilog, system-verilog

An array is called

```
logic [7:0] data_match[1:0];
```

This is assigned value in an `always_comb` block. The values can be one of the following:

```
localparam      MATCHE_PASS  = 2'b00; // match success
localparam      MATCHE_FAIL  = 2'b01; // match failed
localparam      MATCHE_NA    = 2'b10; // match not applicable
```

Now in an `always_comb` block, I assign value to this:

```
logic design_fault;
```

Now `design_fault` is 1'b1 if *any* value inside `data_match` is `MATCHE_FAIL`. Otherwise, it is 1'b0.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

***Using For Loop***

```
always_comb begin
    design_fault = '0;
    for (int i=0; i<8; i=i+1) begin
        design_fault = design_fault | data_match[i]==MATCHE_FAIL;     
    end
end
```

***Using single statement***

Due to your encoding, you can also do it without a loop in a single statement:

```
assign design_fault = |({8{MATCHE_FAIL}} & data_match);
```

But I believe that you first need to change the definition of data_match to be:

```
logic [7:0][1:0] data_match;
```

You first concatenate 8 duplicates of MATCHE_FAIL value.
The data_match vector should be constructed in the same manner - 8 match results concatenated.

This is why you need to change the data_match definition (double check me in simulation).

Then you do bitwise AND between the two.
Since your encoding defines that bitwise AND between MATCHE_FAIL to MACTHE_NA will give "2'b00", and the same for MATCHE_FAIL to MATCHE_PASS, it's enough to check that this bitwise AND result has any bit different than 1'b0.

Therefore, you OR all the bits of the result as the final step.

Answer (score 0):

Use the `inside` operator. See section *11.4.13 Set membership operator* in the [IEEE 1800-2017 SystemVerilog LRM](https://ieeexplore.ieee.org/document/8299595)

```
design_fault = MATCHE_FAIL inside {data_match};
```

Comment: oh, so that depends on whether we have support for SV 2017 in the synthesis and simulation tool right?